# TD Learning formula

Tags: reinforcement-learning

This is something I cannot get my head around and initially I thought is a typo but it is not.

[image]

Essentially in TD learning, we are trying to learn the Value Function. A value function tells me how favourable a state/observation is. Assuming ~~~discount/decay/lambda~~~ factor of 1, if *V(s)* is 10 and I make a move (action *a*) and *V(s')* becomes 5 then I expect reward to be -5:

```
R(a) = V(s') - V(s)
```

Hence in the TD learning formula, when it converges ignoring lambda (regardless of alpha or the learning rate) I expect the *α(r + V(s') - V(s))* to be 0. But if V(s') - V(s) is equal to the reward, then I ended with r + r => 2r!!

So I expect to see *-r* in the formula and not *r*.

So where am I wrong in my thinking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't mean to include lambda factor by the way - a lambda factor of 1 in TD($\lambda$) means you are essentially doing Monte Carlo, not TD, and the update rule you show would be quite different . . . discount factor is most often gamma, $\gamma$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `R(a) = V(s') - V(s)`

This is not correct. The value of a state is based on all its *future* rewards. Your formula would be correct for a value function $V$ that accumulated *past* rewards, but that is not directly useful for action selection in reinforcement learning. The agent needs to choose an action that makes it the most reward in future. It cannot make any action to change what happened in the past, so value functions are forward-looking only. For instance, the value of a state where an agent has completed its task successfully (or failed) is always $0$, because the agent can no longer act, and has no chance of any future reward.

Without discounting, then:

$$V(S_t) = R_{t+1} + V(S_{t+1})$$

Therefore:

$$R_{t+1} = V(S_t) - V(S_{t+1})$$

i.e. the opposite sign than you thought, but compatible with the TD update rule.

Comment: Thank you I originally accepted... but then again, with that formula, if the future reward of V(St+1) is very bad then reward is higher, the worse it is the reward better. This just does not make sense.

Comment: @Aliostad: You are thinking backwards again, about the reward gained so far. If an agent just got a high reward, then it should expect *future* rewards to be less than it thought on the last time step. Because it just got some of that "future" reward right now. The rest of the future will have less expected reward. Eventually at the end, the agent has collected all the reward that it can, so it should expect 0 more reward.

Comment: Or another way to put it - if $R_{t+1}$ is really high, but $V(S_{t+1})$ is really low, it could still be a good choice for the agent, which only cares about the total sum that it gains.

Comment: Thanks for your patience... I think penny dropped! Can't thank you enough.